# Use induction to prove that $a^n + b^n \leq (a+b)^n$

Tags: induction

I am doing some exercises in proving things and I am stuck on this proof:

> $a^n + b^n \leq (a+b)^n$, $a,b > 0$, for every $n > 0$.

I start with $n = 1$: $a^1 + b^1 \leq (a+b)^1$.

Then I assume that $a^n + b^n \leq (a+b)^n$ is true and need to show that
$a^{n+1} + b^{n+1} \leq (a+b)^{n+1}$ is true.

And I am stuck from there on.

I know that
$a^{n+1} + b^{n+1} \leq (a+b)^n \cdot (a+b)$
but I can't get any further.

Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(a+b)^{n+1} = (a+b)^n (a + b) \geq (a^n + b^n)(a + b) = a^{n+1} + ab^n + ba^n + b^{n+1}$.

Can you finish the argument?

Comment: That's exactly how far I am, and I can't figure out how I can form a^n+1+ab^n+ba^n+b^n+1 into a^n+1 + b^n+1

Comment: @user278881 You know $a^{n+1}+ab^n+ba^n+b^{n+1}>a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}$. Therefore $(a+b)^{n+1}>a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}$.

Comment: Ooooh that's obvious, thank you guys >.<